# Foreach Value in Array Check to see if that value is Greater than any value in another Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays which the key is a [part id]. The value is record => Qty:Length. I want to be able to check if any of the values under the same part id from the sencond array is greater than the length of the first array. For example the Part id 2099 in the second array has a qty:length of 14:11.25 and that is greater than the 6:3.33 which I want that to return true in PHP.  I Have a function to split up the qty and length but after that I am unsure where to go. It returns "Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string," Any Help Appreciated.

```
Array
(
    [2099] => Array
        (
            [360] => 6:3.33
            [362] => 14:8.75
        )

    [2130] => Array
        (
            [361] => 4:2.5
        )

)
Array
(
    [2099] => Array
        (
            [360] => 12:8.33
            [362] => 14:11.25
        )

    [2130] => Array
        (
            [361] => 24:3.5
        )

)
```

My PHP:

```
foreach ($a as $partid=>$qty_length){
    $ex_part = explode(":", $qty_length);
}
```

Comment: both have the same keys?

Comment: yes both have the same keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a nested `foreach` loop to find the difference

```
<?php

$array1 = array(2099 => array(360 => "6:3.33",362 => "14:8.75"),2130 => array(361 => "4:2.5"));
$array2 = array(2099 => array(360 => "12:8.33",362 => "14:11.25"),2130 => array(361 => "24:3.5"));

foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {

        // $array1[$key][$key1] get the value of array one curreny key
        // $array2[$key][$key1] get the value of array two current key

        $one = explode(':',$array1[$key][$key1]); // array one value e.g 360 => "6:3.33"
        $two = explode(':',$array2[$key][$key1]); // array two value e.g 360 => "12:8.33"


        // do what ever you want here 
        if($one[0] > $two[0])
        {
            echo "array one key " . $key1 . " is bigger <br>";
        }else{
            echo "array two key " . $key1 . " is bigger <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr =Array
(
        '2099' => Array
        (
                '360' => '6:3.33',
                '362' => '14:8.75'
        ),

        '2130' => Array
        (
                '361' => '4:2.5'
        ),
        '2131' => Array
        (
                '362' => '24:3.5'
        )

);
$arr1=Array
(
        '2099' => Array
        (
                '360' => '12:8.33',
                '362' => '14:11.25'
        ),

        '2130' => Array
        (
                '361' => '24:3.5'
        ),
        '2131' => Array
        (
                '362' => '20:3.5'
        )

);





foreach ($arr as $partid=>$qty_length){

        foreach($qty_length as $key=>$val){
            $ex_part = explode(":", $val);
        //  print_r($ex_part);
            $ex_part1 = $arr1[$partid];
            $len = sizeof($ex_part1);
        foreach( $ex_part1 as $key1=>$val1){    
            $ex_part1 = explode(":", $arr1[$partid][$key1]);
            if($ex_part[0] < $ex_part1[0] && $ex_part[1] < $ex_part1[1]){
                $len--;
                if($len == 0){
                    echo $ex_part1[0]."<br>";
                }else{

                    continue;
                }


            }else if($ex_part[0] >= $ex_part1[0]  && $ex_part[1] >= $ex_part1[1]){

            $len--;
                if($len == 0){
                    echo $ex_part[0]."else <br>";
                }else{

                    continue;
                }

            }
        }

        }

    }
```

you can add more conditions also.